# vis.js network - is there a setting to make the node labels stay the same size on zoom?

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

Basically the title. The client is complaining that when he zooms in, the text labels for the nodes are quite large. Is there a way to keep the node labels at a fixed font size even when zooming in or out?

From the nodes documentation (http://visjs.org/docs/network/nodes.html), there's a scaling.label option, but it doesn't seem to work. I think this is only relevant if I'm using values to scale the nodes.

Comment: I really have no clue on how the option works. I set `label: {min: 14}` and the labels just disappear. There is an [example](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=0010 "Vis Network | Data | Scaling Labels") here, but it seems like the labels are just zoomed without any cutoff

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation:

```
network.on( "zoom", function(properties){
    var options = {
        nodes: {
            // 1/scale to make text larger as scale is smaller
            // 16 is my default font size
            font: {
                size: ( 1 / network.getScale() ) * 16
            }              
        }
    };
    network.setOptions(options);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no such option. The scaling.label option, if I understand correctly what you mean, is used to set a scaling factor, not disable zooming.

However, you can implement this yourself, namely change scaling of labels on zoom. Fortunately, there's `zoom` [event](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/#Events): set a handler like

```
network.on('zoom',rescaleLabels);
```

and implement `rescaleLabels` by setting the corresponding scale factor to their labels. In there, you can use `network.getScale()` to get new scale and then set `scaling` of [nodes](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/nodes.html).

Comment: I still don't know how to implement this. Can you give more instruction?

Comment: @Ooker well, I don't have a solution at hand and worked with vis a while ago, but I've updated the link and added a couple of hints (you still have to find out how to edit nodes on the go, I've only used [manipulation](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/manipulation.html) methods for that which is not this case).