# Can labels be hidden by default, but shown when the node is selected?

Tags: label, zooming, vis.js-network

I want my graph has no label by default, but when I select a node its label will show up. There is [`chosen.label`](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/nodes.html) that seems promising, but I still don't know how to write the function. There is also [a question about `scaling.label`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47216649/3416774), but as indicated in there it also seems not working.

<sub>Another approach is to have a checkbox to turn on and off the labels. See: [Can the filter in the configure option specify an only option?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69727718/3416774)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using the `chosen.label` option in combination with the [transparent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#transparent_keyword) font color.

In the options object firstly set the default font color for nodes to transparent, then within chosen.label adjust it to a visible color.

```js
var options = {
  nodes: {
    font: {
      // Set default label font color to transparent
      color: "transparent"
    },
    chosen: {
      label: function(values, id, selected, hovering) {
        // Adjust label font color so it is visible
        // Updates to the values object are applied to the network
        values.color = "#343434";
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Working example is below.

```js
// create an array with nodes
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
  { id: 1, label: "Node 1" },
  { id: 2, label: "Node 2" },
  { id: 3, label: "Node 3" }
]);

// create an array with edges
var edges = new vis.DataSet([
  { from: 1, to: 3 },
  { from: 1, to: 2 },
  { from: 3, to: 3 },
]);

// create a network
var container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
var treeData = {
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges,
};
var options = {
  nodes: {
    font: {
      // Set default label font color to transparent
      color: "transparent"
    },
    chosen: {
      label: function(values, id, selected, hovering) {
        // Adjust label font color so it is visible
        // Updates to the values object are applied to the network
        values.color = "#343434";
      }
    }
  }
};
var network = new vis.Network(container, treeData, options);
```

```css
#mynetwork {
  width: 600px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script>
<div id="mynetwork"></div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to select multiple nodes at the same times?

Comment: Yes it's possible to select multiple, the multiselect option under interaction has to be set to true `interaction: { multiselect: true }`. Once this is set you can CTRL + Click to select multiple, the documentation for this is [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/interaction.html). Working example based on the above is at https://jsfiddle.net/1fe7wq0k/